# pandas. join resampled df with original df by data range

Tags: python, pandas

I need to join 2 dataframes based on a datetime range.
I've already googled/stacktraced for it and found some possible work arounds.

Since I resample the data and want to join the aggregated version back to the original, I thought that there might be a way to simulate the resampling by adding a "join criteria column" which represents the possible aggregated datetime.

this is my base:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import quandl

df = quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")
df = df.ix[:, ['Close']]

print('***************** ORIG')
print(df.head(10).to_string())

ac = df['Close'].resample('3D').mean()

print('***************** RESAMPLED')
print(ac.head(10).to_string())


frames = [ac]
ac2 = pd.concat(frames, axis=1, join='inner')

print('***************** RESAMPLED 2')
print(ac2.head(10).to_string())



#new = pd.merge(df, ac2, on=df.index, how='left')  

#print('***************** JOIN')
#print(new.to_string())
```

and this is the output:

```
***************** ORIG
              Close
Date               
2004-08-19  100.335
2004-08-20  108.310
2004-08-23  109.400
2004-08-24  104.870
2004-08-25  106.000
2004-08-26  107.910
2004-08-27  106.150
2004-08-30  102.010
2004-08-31  102.370
2004-09-01  100.250
***************** RESAMPLED
Date
2004-08-19    104.322500
2004-08-22    107.135000
2004-08-25    106.686667
2004-08-28    102.010000
2004-08-31    101.376667
2004-09-03    100.010000
2004-09-06    101.940000
2004-09-09    103.820000
2004-09-12    109.495000
2004-09-15    114.486667
Freq: 3D
```

pretty cool would be, if I could calculate a new column

```
***************** ORIG
              Close   newDate
Date               
2004-08-19  100.335   2004-08-19
2004-08-20  108.310   2004-08-19
2004-08-23  109.400   2004-08-22
2004-08-24  104.870   2004-08-22
2004-08-25  106.000   2004-08-25
2004-08-26  107.910   2004-08-25 
2004-08-27  106.150   2004-08-25 
2004-08-30  102.010   2004-08-28
2004-08-31  102.370   2004-08-31
2004-09-01  100.250   2004-08-31
```

and use this a join criteria...

but I am not eager to re-programm the resample in a loop ... if you want to suggest that ... :)

any ideas?

Thanks!
E.

**** EDIT ****
I've found that solution to shift the date. now i'm able to join :)

```
print('***************** RESAMPLED 2')
ac2['folgep'] = ac2.index.shift(1)
ac2['DatumJoin'] = ac2.index
print(ac2.head(10).to_string())


df['matched'] = np.piecewise(df.index, [(df.index >= start_date)&(df.index <= end_date) for start_date, end_date in zip(ac2.index, ac2.folgep.values)], ac2.DatumJoin)

print('***************** after join')
print(df.head(10).to_string())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) your resampled data:

```
df['Close3D'] = df.Close.resample('3D').mean().reindex(df.index, method='ffill')
```

Comment: great solution! no need for joining anymore :) thanks!! @emulbreh

Comment: This is a perfect solution. I had resorted to resampling the my whole dataframe and then exploding it back out thus losing detail, but this gives the best of both worlds. Using it to calculate different timeframe technicals on stock market data. i.e. 20min moving average on 1min candle data. Thanks!